# C# not picking up change in ASP or HTML elements

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have a few dynamic html items which are populated by jquery and/or JS, but for some reason the C# will only see the original values from when the page loaded.

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-3">Date</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-9">
                                    <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="tsm" runat="server" />
                                    <asp:TextBox CssClass="btn btn-default pull-right" ID="calBtn" runat="server" Style="width: 150px">Click Here</asp:TextBox>
                                    <asp:CalendarExtender ID="calExt" TargetControlID="calBtn" runat="server" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-5">
                                    Start (Actual Begin Time)</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-7">
                                    <%--<input runat="server" id="startTime" class="time btn btn-default pull-right" type="text" autocomplete="off" style="width: 150px" />--%>
                                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="startTime" CssClass="time btn btn-default pull-right" AutoCompleteType="Disabled" Style="width: 150px"></asp:TextBox>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-4">End</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-8">
                                    <%--<input runat="server" id="endTime" class="time btn btn-default pull-right disabled" type="text" autocomplete="off" style="width: 150px" />--%>
                                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="endTime" CssClass="time btn btn-default pull-right" AutoCompleteType="Disabled" Style="width: 150px"></asp:TextBox>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
```

Above the asp:TextBox items I have commented out my original "input" elements since I was trying both methods. If I call `string date = calBtn.Text` in the C#, it says "Click here" as the returned value. I have also tried `date = calExt.SelectedDate` which returns empty.

In the text box I have tried `.Text` and `.SelectedValue` but still empty.

Comment: Not sure if you have it somewhere else, but the form does need a `runat="server"`.

Comment: @DrewKennedy I do have it outside that section. This snippet is just a small part of the whole form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@DrewKennedy had the right idea. I was nesting all these `<form>` tags for the Bootstrap which caused it to not be seen server-side. I had wrongly assumed I needed the nested forms to make the CSS work.

I already had a `<form runat="server">` surrounding the whole body, but changing the inner `<form class="form-horizontal">` to `<div class="form-horizontal">` fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET only support ONE SINGLE . So you had to add **runat=server** on your form makup.

Now it is working for me.